# How should I pronounce Spanish single 'r' and 'l'?

Tags: pronunciación

I have the same problem as most Asian Spanish learners with the Spanish single 'r' and 'l'. We usually mispronounce 'ala' as 'ara',  and bra, bla. bre.ble .... etc are difficult for me to speak them accurately. So how should I pronounce single 'r' and 'l' correctly?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I learn to roll my R's?](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/1273/can-i-learn-to-roll-my-rs)

Comment: hard to write how to pronounce something. TO learn pronunciation I can only recommend yo u to talk to natives and practice.

Comment: @Rafa: There are ways to write phonetically.

Comment: check this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iH-9lqrGbBU

Comment: @Flimzy: Sure, I know, and the "fonemas" for r and l are clearly described in every spanish manual. I think the problem of zhang is how to pronounce it correctly and not what is the phoneme.

Comment: As a sidebar, please note that "r" and "l" confusion is not limited to Asians.  It's endemic.  Note the way the country name, "Argelia" is written.  Compare to the way the same country name is written in English or French.

Answer (score 1):

I think the basical thing is that, when you have your tongue up  to pronounce "r" you have to make it vibrate, and to pronounce the "l" you don't (you better push your tongue against your palate) .

Answer (score 1):

It actually depends on where the r is located in the word:

At the beginning after «l», «n», «s» or prefix «sub-» is pronounced as /r/

In other positions is pronounced as /ɾ/

l is always pronounced as /l/

You can check [this pronunciation page](http://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wikcionario:Referencia/ES/Pronunciaci%C3%B3n) to listen some samples.